# Get ComboBox to Display MySql Database Foreign Key Column That References to String on Vb.Net

Tags: mysql, vb.net, datagridview, combobox, foreign-keys

I am coding a program that basically allows the user to see (in a DataGridView) a mysql database table. However, I included an option to edit/add data to this table, through binding textboxes to the VARCHAR fields (such as Name, Adress, email) and updating the values or inserting them, if they do not exist. However several of the table columns are foreign keys that refer to other tables - not to their respective foreign keys, but to a VARCHAR field that contains the description of the data.

Let me give examples.

I have a main table that is like:

```
CREATE TABLE staff (
memberId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
nameVARCHAR(30),
profession VARCHAR(30),
FOREIGN KEY (profession) REFERENCES professionstable(professionName))
```

Whereas the professionstable is like this:

```
CREATE TABLE professionstabe (
professionId INT PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
professionName VARCHAR(30))
```

The goal of this is that I can previously insert all the professions in this table (preventing people from typing wrong), and if I have a need to insert more professions this can be done smoothly (which is why I dont use ENUM).

So I do INSERT INTO professionstable VALUE (NULL, "doctor"), and then attorney, businessman, etc.

In the real db I have several fields such as this, like Gender, State, Nacionality etc etc.

Back there in my VB.net code, I made normal mysql connections, table adapters to select * from staff, dataset and datatable and normally .Fill etc.

However, when I bind the combobox to this data, using

```
ComboBox1.DataSource = MyDataSource
ComboBox1.ValueMember = "professionId"
ComboBox1.DisplayMember = "professionName"
```

What happens is that, when a particular row is selected in the DataGridView, I don't get a combobox that shows all the possible types of the professions column in staff table (which ought to be all the professionName rows existing) being the selected item the one that is actually this row's one in the database.

E.g: I inserted a row that the name is John. Having insert the rows in the professionName "attorney", "doctor", "bussinessman", I inserted to John "attorney".

When this is loaded in the combobox, it will show all the professions I have inserted, like "doctor", "businessman", "attorney", and when I select another one (John's is "attorney"), such as "doctor", the other fields won't remain as they are so that I can update the table and make John a doctor. Instead, they will just "filter" for all the other rows in which the profession column is "doctor".

I have tried to do it in different ways, from datarelations to enums, but all without sucess. Also I dont want to make the FOREIGN KEY reference the ID, because if I do it the user on the datagridview will just see the professionId, whereas I want him to be able to see the professionName.

Can anyone please help me?
Thanks alot!